# Save an array to file in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, dictionary

I am building an application which will:

1. Check internet connection;
2. Receive JSON file from server and store data in file if server is reachable;
3. Read from file if connection to server is down.

Right now I managed to implement connection checking, receiving JSON, putting data to array.

Received JSON looks like this:

[image]

Then I am using the following peace of code to create an array of dictionaries to store JSON data. Array of dictionaries was chosen to be able to filter it and then using values' keys to reach values.

```
var rates = [ExchangeRates]()  //instance of class Rate
var bnkDct  =  ["bank": "", "currency": "","buyrate": "", "sellrate": ""] //template
var indx : Int = 0 //index for iteration

            for rate in jsonData{
                let rate = ExchangeRates(data: rate as! NSDictionary)

                rates.append(rate)

                    bnkDct["bank"] = rates[indx].bank
                    bnkDct["buyrate"] = rates[indx].buyRate
                    bnkDct["sellrate"] = rates[indx].sellRate
                    bnkDct["currency"] = rates[indx].currency

                self.bankDict.append(bnkDct)
                indx += 1
            }
```

After this I have an array which looks like:

[image]

Now I would like to save this array to a file and obviously to be able to read it.

I was trying to write data using something like this:

```
        let filePath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "MyData.dat"

        self.bankDict.writeToFile(filePath, automatically: true)
```

But it gives me an error : "[(Dictionary)] doesn't have writeToFile member".

Also I can't cast it as NSDictionary to use the same **writeToFile** method.

Also I was trying to write data using something like this:

```
        let filePath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "MyData.dat"

        NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(self.bankDict, toFile: filePath)
```

It creates a file with strange encoding:

[image]

And when I am trying to read it:

```
 let newDictionary = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(filePath) as! [Dictionary <String,AnyObject> ]
```

I receive the error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Also debugger shows very "interesting" thing:

[image]

newDictionary variable has zillion of values. There were 40 dictionaries in array which was written in file.

**Can anybody advice what I am doing wrong here or maybe I am using bad practices doing something here?**

Comment: I think you should have a look into *Core Data*. Here is a good link to start: http://www.raywenderlich.com/85578/first-core-data-app-using-swift

Comment: Remove the typecast `as! [Dictionary <String,AnyObject> ]` and see what the value is.

Comment: My guess is that you're loosing the saved file between app launches because the `NSTemporaryDirectory` path changes everytime the app launches. Solution would be to save it to a permanent location. As for `newDictionary` and its zillion items, it's just the debugger freaking out because it can't find the actual variable content if stopped after the variable declaration but before it is filled. I bet the variable is actually empty.

Comment: @EricD. Thanks for reply, but it seems that it finds file well. I am using function: 
        func getFileURL(fileName: String) -> NSURL {
            let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
            let dirURL = manager.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false, error: nil)
            return dirURL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
        }
        
    let filePath = getFileURL("MyData.dat").path!

and I tried to compare file paths they match.

Comment: @Adam when I remove typecast it shows me warning. If I ran application it uses AnyObject?  type and value is  nil

Comment: Consider that an `Array` of `[String:String]` writes a property list file which has a file extension `plist`

Comment: @vadian it is not [string: String]. there are other datatypes. and there is no difference, you can use whatever extension you like. it is not the case unfortunately

Comment: The template `bnkDct ` is `[String:String]` and the screen shot showing the array is an `Array` of  `[String:String]` as well or at least property list compliant types

Comment: @vadian namings are a bit confusing in my project. bnkDct - yes it is string:String. But I was printing bankDict variable and was trying to write it to file. it is [String: AnyObject]

Comment: according to your code the array `bankDict` contains `bnkDct` objects, so `bankDict` is `Array<[String:String]>`

Comment: Can you share your code with me?? The one for saving response from json in a file.. I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the array or dictionary writeToFile methods unless every object in your object graph is a property list object. (A small list of types. Look it up.)

You have a custom class, ExchangeRates, in your array.

Similarly you can't save a file with NSKeyedArchiver unless every object in your object graph conforms to the NSCoding protocol. If you add support for NSCoding to your ExchangeRates class then your second approach will work, but the file contents will not be human-readable.

Comment: Can you explain how should I use NSCoding?

Comment: Perfect link for an introduction to NSCoding. Thank you for adding that.